# Understand this Fourier transform $\int \frac{1}{|x|}e^{ikx} d^3 x = \frac{4 \pi}{k^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, fourier-analysis

I found the equation

$$\int \frac{1}{|x|}e^{ikx} d^3 x = \frac{4 \pi}{k^2}$$

in a 'physics' textbook and I just don't understand what this equation tries to tell me. Is there anybody who understands this calculation? I just don't see it, cause I interpreted this as a 3d- integral over the norm, but I guess that this integral would not converge. Especially, I don't know the limits, though this $4 \pi$ factor looks very much like the angular integral in spherical coordinates.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I bet on the $3D$ Fourier transformation. Inside the exponential, there is a scalar product, and the squared norm of $k$ in the RHS.

Comment: could you explain why this 3d transform converges? Normally you would have $4 \pi \int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^2}{r}e^{ikr} dr$ there in spherical coordinates, or am I wrong?

Comment: This Fourier transform has to be understood in the sense of tempered distributions.

Comment: @Dominik could you explain this a little bit more( probably this would serve as an answer then)

Comment: Going to spherical coordinates we have $I = \int r e^{i|k|r\cos \theta} \sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$. Now change $r\to |k| r$ and we get $I = \frac{1}{|k|^2}\int r e^{ir\cos \theta} \sin\theta drd\theta d\phi$

Comment: @Winther but still, this integral would not converge, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a rough way to go:

Denote \begin{align}
I(k)=\int_{R^3}\frac{1}{|x|}e^{i \vec{k}\vec{x}}d^3x
\end{align}

1.) Introduce spherical coordinates $(r, \phi, \theta)$, with $|\det(J)|=r^2 sin(\phi)$.

2.) Choose the Orientation of $\vec{k}$ as along the $z$-Axis: $\vec{k}\vec{x}=k r \cos(\phi) $

3.)  $kr \rightarrow r$ which gives us a nice $1/k^2$ overall factor

3.)  Do the trivial $\theta$ integral, so $2\pi$ shows up

4.)  Carry out the nearly trivial $\phi$ integral. You should have something like \begin{align}I(k)=\frac{2\pi}{i k^2}\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{-ir }-e^{ir }\right)dr
\end{align}

5.) the crucial step is now to interpret this integral. As a comment suggest this has to be interpreted in a distributional sense. For computational purposes it is sufficient to add a small imaginary part to $r$ so that the integrals converge: $k\rightarrow r\pm i\delta $

6.) Take the limit $\delta \rightarrow 0  $ and you're done:

\begin{align}
I(k)=\frac{4\pi}{k^2}
\end{align}

Is this enough, so you can fill in the rest for yourself?

Comment: Actually, the only problem is this last last integral that is supposed to converge in the distributional sense. I still don't see quite through how this works...